# How to get post URL using FQL or Facebook Graph API

Tags: url, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-fql, facebook-group

I can get post ids  but FQL has not command like

```
"SELECT url FROM stream WHERE post_id = "45648967486_48564864856"
```

This is my code:

```
List<String> queryResults = facebookClient.executeFqlQuery("SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id=192380824177133", String.class);
```

Now, I have got list of post ids and I want to get url's of these posts.

```
List<String> url= facebookClient.executeFqlQuery(("SELECT permalink FROM stream WHERE post_id='192380824177133_478562935558919'"), String.class);
```

This command gives me only permalink like [this](https://www.facebook.com/groups/192380824177133/permalink/478562935558919)

but I want [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0AIIsfKGlV8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the URL of the posts use:

```
"SELECT attachment FROM stream WHERE post_id = "45648967486_48564864856"
```